# laravel join gives wrong id

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have the following query:

```
\DB::table('Service_prices')
                        ->join('Services', 'Services.id', 'Service_prices.service_id')
                        ->join('Roles', 'Roles.id', 'Service_prices.id')
                        ->join('Users', 'Users.role_id', 'Roles.id')
                        ->where('Services.id', $service_id)
                        ->select(['Service_prices.id as service_price_id', 'Roles.id as role_id', 'Service_id as service_id'])
                        ->get();
```

the issue is that all tables has id and I need them all, but, I get same id for all, in other words it appears there is some conflict and one of the ids are overwriting the others.
how to solve this?

Comment: Don't you think the **roles join** should be `->join('Roles', 'Roles.id', 'Service_prices.role_id')`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
\DB::table('Service_prices')
     ->join('Services', 'Services.id', 'Service_prices.service_id')
     ->join('Roles', 'Roles.id', 'Service_prices.id')
     ->join('Users', 'Users.role_id', 'Roles.id')
     ->where('Services.id', $service_id)
     ->select('Service_prices.id as service_price_id', 'Roles.id as role_id', 'Services.id as service_id', 'users.id as user_id')
     ->get();
```